# cypher query not getting result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have question on cyper.I don't know how to execute

Find a list of books no-one likes.

i wrote the following query

```
MATCH (b1:Book),(R:Reader)
WITH R,b1
OPTIONAL MATCH (b1)--(L:LIKES)--(R)
WHERE L IS NULL
RETURN b1.title
```

I am getting some result  but i think it is wrong.

when i execute the below query, i can see the relation in the graph

MATCH (b1:Book),(R:Reader)
WITH R,b1
OPTIONAL MATCH (b1)--(L:LIKES)--(R)
WHERE L IS NULL
RETURN b1,R

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49cA9.png)

2)Find all pairs of people that have no liked books in common.

i wasnt able to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for the books no one likes then you don't need to look at people at all, just books. Here is a query to return the list of books nobody likes.

```
MATCH (b:Book) 
WHERE NOT (b)<--(:LIKES)
RETURN b
```

If nobody likes a book isn't that your entire community of people that don't like the book?

Here are all the Readers that have not liked a book.

```
MATCH (r:Reader) 
WHERE NOT (r)--(:LIKES)
RETURN r
```

Comment: the question says  Find all pairs of people that have no liked books in common.

shouldnt the answer contain pair of people. i mean two people

Answer (score 0):

1. MATCH (b:book) 
   WHERE NOT ((:Reader)-[:LIKES]->(b:book)) 
   RETURN b

   2. MATCH (R1:Reader), (R2:Reader)
      WITH R1, R2
      OPTIONAL MATCH (R1)--(b:book)--(R2)
      WHERE b IS NULL
      RETURN R1.name, R2.name

Answer (score 0):

You actually have 2 questions. These answers may work for you:

(1) Find all `Book`s that no `Reader` `LIKES`:

```
MATCH (b:Book)
WHERE NOT EXISTS((b)<-[:LIKES]-(:Reader))
RETURN b;
```

(2) Find all `Reader` pairs that do not like any of the same `Book`s:

```
MATCH (r:Reader)
OPTIONAL MATCH (r)-[:LIKES]->(b:Book)
WITH r, COLLECT(b) AS books
WITH COLLECT({r: r, books: books}) AS data
RETURN REDUCE(s = [], i1 IN RANGE(0, SIZE(data)-2) |
  s + REDUCE(t = [], i2 IN RANGE(i1+1, SIZE(data)-1) |
    CASE WHEN SIZE(apoc.coll.intersection(data[i1].books, data[i2].books)) = 0
      THEN t + [data[i1], data[i2]]
      ELSE t END
  )
) AS dissimilar_pairs
```

`OPTIONAL MATCH` is used so that `Reader`s that like no books will also be considered. The APOC function [apoc.coll.intersection](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index33.html#_collection_functions) is used to get the intersection of 2 lists.